# How to take top 1 rows for based on Datetime variation in SQL Server using Inner Join query?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables called `TableA` & `TableB`.

I used an inner join on these tables, and get these results:

```
Sno    Operation    StartTime               EndTime    
------ ----------- ---------------------  ---------------------
1        OP10       2017-03-01 07:00:00    2017-03-01 07:10:00
1        OP10       2017-03-01 07:10:00    2017-03-01 07:20:00
1        OP10       2017-03-01 07:25:00    2017-03-01 07:30:00
2        OP20       2017-03-01 08:00:00    2017-03-01 08:10:00
2        OP20       2017-03-01 08:20:00    2017-03-01 08:30:00
3        OP30       2017-03-01 09:00:00    2017-03-01 09:10:00
3        OP30       2017-03-01 10:00:00    2017-03-01 10:10:00
```

I need an output like below format, based on greatest `Endtime` to get `Top(1)` rows for each group.

E.g: Needed output like this:

```
     Sno    Operation    StartTime               EndTime    
    ------ ----------- ---------------------  ---------------------    
    1        OP10       2017-03-01 07:25:00    2017-03-01 07:30:00   
    2        OP20       2017-03-01 08:20:00    2017-03-01 08:30:00    
    3        OP30       2017-03-01 10:00:00    2017-03-01 10:10:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one:

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE(sno INT,Operation varchar(10)  ,StartTime Datetime,EndTime Datetime)
INSERT @tb
SELECT 1,        'OP10',       '2017-03-01 07:00:00',    '2017-03-01 07:10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1   ,     'OP10' ,      '2017-03-01 07:10:00',    '2017-03-01 07:20:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1   ,     'OP10' ,      '2017-03-01 07:25:00',    '2017-03-01 07:30:00'UNION ALL
SELECT 2   ,     'OP20',       '2017-03-01 08:00:00',    '2017-03-01 08:10:00'UNION ALL
SELECT 2    ,    'OP20',       '2017-03-01 08:20:00',    '2017-03-01 08:30:00'UNION ALL
SELECT 3     ,   'OP30',       '2017-03-01 09:00:00',    '2017-03-01 09:10:00'UNION ALL
SELECT 3    ,    'OP30',       '2017-03-01 10:00:00' ,   '2017-03-01 10:10:00'





select sno,operation, max(starttime),max(endtime) from @tb group by sno,operation
```

Result:

```
1   OP10    2017-03-01 07:25:00.000 2017-03-01 07:30:00.000
2   OP20    2017-03-01 08:20:00.000 2017-03-01 08:30:00.000
3   OP30    2017-03-01 10:00:00.000 2017-03-01 10:10:00.000
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. What if starttime was not a max value for max endtime?

Comment: @Dhamo - If you try this solution on a slightly different dataset, you'll know  that this isn't the right answer. Plus won't work if you want to get other columns corresponding to max end date

Comment: you had a big problem @GurV i'm just helping someone no other than.. if my solution helped him then fine, if not then fine too. But he says this is what he wanted.. Why you always contest that this is not an answer?

Comment: I just want to tell you @GurV, i'm just here to help with no other intentions.. Help and learn to someone too. Thanks to your comment.

Comment: @reds - it's not contest. It about *actually* helping. If your answer give a sense of being correct but is actually not, then you are not helping even if you think you are. The community should decide through moderation if it's actually helpful. In your case though, it seems most of the community people got it wrong too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by sno,
            operation order by endtime desc
            ) rn
    from your_table t
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Max()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) and [Group by](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server) functions. It will return the max top 1 rows and grouped by operations and sno.

```
select Sno,max(Operation) as Operation,max(StartTime) as 
starttime,max(EndTime) as endtime from dbo.TableExample group by Operation,Sno
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select *
from (
select ABC.*,row_number() over (partition by Operation order by endtime desc) row_n
from ABC 
) a
where row_n = 1;
```